# APK size is too big because of audio files

Tags: java, audio, apk

I'm working on my own Ebook application. My book has a total of 15 chapters, so I have a list with 15 elements - each one is a string with all the chapter's text.

I also have 15 .ogg files that I paid a voice over talent to record. The size of my final APK is almost 97MB, where about 90MB of them are a result of my audio files.

What can I do in order to reduce the APK to 25MB or less and yet give my users the option to listen to the narration?

Comment: Can you compress the audio format into something more lightweight like MP3? If it's spoken word, it can get a reduced bitrate as well compared to music.

Comment: Ogg is a better option, because I compressed these files from MP3 files.

Comment: You can always host the audio on an external server. The downside is your users won't be able to listen while offline unless you cache the audio locally.

Comment: How do I host my files (for free) and read them using Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into **[Google Play Dynamic Delivery](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/dynamic-delivery)** with the Android App Bundle.

This allows to split your Android app in modules, some of which you could download on-demand at runtime.

Effectively, this would allow you to download the .ogg only when the user needs them, or pre-load them if you can predict which ones are going to be listened to next (e.g. if they have an order).